# How do I get a div background image to scroll?

Tags: css

I want the background image of a div (with id="library_tracks") to be repeated in both x and y directions and to scroll with the div. For whatever reason, the background is staying fixed. I imagine the solution is pretty straight forward... any ideas?

Here's my CSS:

```
#library_tracks {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 400px;
    border: thin solid #DADADA;
    background-image: url('../img/track_background.png');
    background-attachment: scroll;

}
```

Comment: can you either post a link, or show a simplified example at [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is to set the background not on the container div, but on the content div within it. [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/Cj29C/) where the `<div id="library_tracks">` div displays the scrollbar, but the `<div id="content">` is the actual content that's moved.

http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/Cj29C/

This works because it's the content div that moves. The library_tracks div is stationary, but everything in it scrolls.

Comment: Correct and thorough response! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A entire divison will scroll on only one circumstance i.e. the contains does not fit within the division area.

Whether you have small background images or big one, if the ***content can fit*** within the div we will *not* get the scrolling even if you set the overflow option.